# Using subquery in MySQL

Tags: mysql, subquery

I need some help with a specific problem about subqueries in MySQL. This is a shortversion of the problem I have:

I have table 1 and 2 where table 1 have a column called "SupplyID" which corresponds with table 2's "ID". I need to get a list with stuff from one single supplier.

I tried with this but didn't work:

```
select name
from item
where SupplyID exists (
   select *
   from SupplyID
   where SupplyID = ID
);
```

Comment: You need [this](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp) if you want to show it in one table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select name from item i where exists (select * from table2 t where i.SupplyID = t.ID);
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked but what if I need to get one single ID? Is there an easier solution than needing to have the ID in the command?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your tables are named  table1 and table2 you 
You could use a inner join

```
select distinct t1.name
from ybale  as t1 
inner join table2 as t2 on t1.ID = t2.SupplyID
```

Answer (score 0):

My answer is more like to what scaisEdge answered here but I strongly recommend to do this with `LEFT JOIN`. and If you want to select just one ID, for example ID=10

```
SELECT T1.name
FROM item AS T1
LEFT JOIN SupplyID AS T2 ON T2.SupplyID=T1.ID
WHERE T1.ID = 10
```